# Random.Next C# doesnt work like i want

Tags: c#, random

I try to create a daily reward system. But i got one problem.

First the code :

```
Random rndDailyItem = new Random();
short[] itemIds = { 9023, 9041 };
rndDailyItem.Next(0, itemIds.Length);
```

So, the problem is: I want the "itemIds" as output, but the output i got for now is just 0 or 1, what did i wrong?

The "rest" of the code is this:

EDIT:

```
                if (rndDailyItem != null)
                {

                    session.Character.DailyBonus = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

                    session.Character.SendGift(session.Character.CharacterId, Convert.ToInt16(rndDailyItem.Next(0, itemIds.Length)), Convert.ToByte(rndDailyAmount.Next(0, itemAmount.Length)),
                        0, 0, false);
                    session.SendPacket(
                        session.Character.GenerateSay(Language.Instance.GetMessageFromKey("DAILY_RECEIVED"), 10));
                }
                else
                {
                    session.SendPacket(
                        UserInterfaceHelper.GenerateMsg(Language.Instance.GetMessageFromKey("ERROR_MESSAGE"),
                            0));
                }
```

Here is a bigger part of the code. I cant add that much code lines i want, cuz stackoverflow tell me its to much code. Sorry. Thanks for help

Comment: Why not add the "rest" (what's the difference between "rest" and rest? :-) of the code to your actual code, so we have a continuous report of the code you are running? And while you're at it, post code that can compile, not an approximation (`CharacterId, Convert...`). Code is a precise thing, so when you ask questions, you need to be precise too.

Comment: "but the output i got" is nothing. According to the code that you posted, there is no output. We shouldn't have to guess because you don't post the code.

Comment: Edited. I cant do any more. Hopeful you can help me now.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you need to use the random *index* you got to access the item you want.

```
short[] itemIds = { 9023, 9041 };
int index = rnd.Next(0, itemIds.Length);
short here_is_the_value = itemIds[index];
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me. It's just do the code after this line 
"return itemIds[index];" 
unreachable.

Comment: haha, alright, I changed the return to just declaring a variable :)